# how to insert in to database using prepared statments in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

hello i am a java developer but new to php here i am trying to insert data in to the database using prepared statements as mentioned in here http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php but i am getting an error may i know what sort of error is this and any help to resolve this.

**Error:** Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in G:****\xampp\htdocs****\registrationControl.php on line 17

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "ksbka");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username_first']);
$username_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username_email']);
$username_tele = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username_tele']);
echo $firstname."@@@@@".$username_email;

$query="INSERT INTO instructorregistration (Id, Name, email, telephone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$pst = $con->prepare($query);
$pst->bindParam(1, "");
$pst->bindParam(2, $firstname);
$pst->bindParam(3, $username_email);
$pst->bindParam(4, $username_tele);
$pst->execute();
if (!mysqli_query($con,$pst)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You're mixin `mysqli` and `pdo`, these are different APIs

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php in this link it is combining both mysqli and pdo can you please elobrate what i am supposed to do.

Comment: There's no PDO code in examples on the page you provided.

Comment: they aren't mixing the apis, you have to write bind_param instead of bindParam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you want to use `bindParam()` method, the value should be an instance of PDOStatement .

The doc you see as bellow:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
```

`$dbh` is a PDO instance, I think, NOT mysqli instance. Because there is no `mysqli::bindParam()`.

To solve this problem, you can:

1. use PDO class instead of Mysqli
2. create the query as the simplest way:

   ```
   $query="INSERT INTO instructorregistration (Id, Name, email, telephone) VALUES (NULL, $firstname, $username_email, $username_tele)";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the mysqli methods, when you use mysqli

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param(1, "");
...
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
/* explicit close recommended */
$stmt->close();

/* Non-prepared statement */
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM test");
var_dump($res->fetch_all());
```

edit: added some code from the official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)